# How to reallocate disk partitions

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, lvm

I used an installer usb flash drive to get Ubuntu 22.04 server onto a Windows mini pc. I asked the installer to wipe Windows since the machine will be a standalone server with Linux only.

I got / with only 100G of the 1T ssd.

```
pat@angel:~$ df -h 
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  8.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   93G 1008K 100% /
tmpfs                              7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2.0G  254M  1.6G  14% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000

pat@angel:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop1                       7:1    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop2                       7:2    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop3                       7:3    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop4                       7:4    0  40.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19993
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0 950.8G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

I'd like / to have all of nvme0n1p3 (about 1T) without wrecking anything already in ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv since I have all ubuntu and config there. Not sure how I got this result. If I have an lvm why isn't it all of the available disk/partition? If I have to reinstall, what did I do wrong the first time?

Better than a reinstall, can I effectively merge ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv with the rest of nvme0n1p3 to get one ~1T partition or lvm, if so how?

Comment: After some research: Since I want to extend the lvm on a single partition it seems like I can extend via vmextend then resize the fs using xfs_growfs?

Comment: This looks like a Ubuntu server install. Typically the installer gives you a 100G root partition which is plenty for the system. Generally you would create other volume groups for server application data. The other 850G should be available for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had the same problem, and I used pvs and pvsresize to fix my problem:

```
sudo pvs
sudo pvresize /dev/nvme0n1p3
sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

You then run df -h to check that it reallocated correctly.

```
serbu@itchigo:/dev$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              767M  1.8M  765M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  936G   93G  804G  11% /
tmpfs                              3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2.0G  252M  1.6G  14% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              767M  4.0K  767M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005974/cannot-use-mkdir-in-home-directory-permission-denied-linux-lubuntu